# Sharing data from Instagram (Android Development)

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram, sharing

I am trying to share data (Photo, location, captions) from Instagram to my application. I understand that there is a share button with every photo, and so how can I share all the data associated with this post to my application via this sharing button? Most of the sharing actions seems to be sharing from the developing app to the Instagram app. I cannot find any information regarding sharing from Instagram to my app. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Too accept shared data you need to specify an `<intent filter>` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: In what form would the data be sent to my application? How would I accept the data from Instagram?

Comment: @user6685927 It will come as an Bundle in the parameter to onCreate(). You will need to research the exact details of what data Instagram puts in the Bundle.